# Overloading of qwt setPen does not work

Tags: c++, qt, qwt

I wanted to compile the following code:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <qwt_plot.h>
#include <qwt_plot_curve.h>
#include <qwt_plot_grid.h>
#include <qwt_symbol.h>
#include <qwt_legend.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QwtPlot plot;
    plot.setTitle( "Plot Demo" );
    plot.setCanvasBackground( Qt::white );
    plot.setAxisScale( QwtPlot::yLeft, 0.0, 10.0);
    plot.insertLegend( new QwtLegend() );

    QwtPlotGrid *grid = new QwtPlotGrid();
    grid->attach( &plot );

    QwtPlotCurve *curve = new QwtPlotCurve();
    curve->setTitle( "Pixel Count" );
    curve->setPen( Qt::blue, 4 ),
    curve->setRenderHint( QwtPlotItem::RenderAntialiased, true );

    QwtSymbol *symbol = new QwtSymbol( QwtSymbol::Ellipse,
        QBrush( Qt::yellow ), QPen( Qt::red, 2 ), QSize( 8, 8 ) );
    curve->setSymbol( symbol );

    QPolygonF points;
    points << QPointF( 0.0, 4.4 ) << QPointF( 1.0, 3.0 )
        << QPointF( 2.0, 4.5 ) << QPointF( 3.0, 6.8 )
        << QPointF( 4.0, 7.9 ) << QPointF( 5.0, 7.1 );
    curve->setSamples( points );

    curve->attach( &plot );

    plot.resize( 600, 400 );
    plot.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

But I get the error "No matching function to call for QwtPlotCurve::setPen(...). Candidate is "QwtPlotCurve::setPen(const QPen&)". But according to the documentation (http://qwt.sourceforge.net/class_qwt_plot_curve.html#ae00bd073a2bcf7c3c810d70af1f86750) this function should be overloaded, on the one hand as `setPen(const QPen&)`, but on the other hand as `setPen(const QColor & color, qreal width = 0.0, Qt::PenStyle style Qt::SolidLine)`, but my QT compiler does not recognize this second overloading variable. Why? I already entered the necessary variables into the *.pro-file.

Edit: I could solve this problem by creating a QPen and added the necessary features manually, but this should only be a temporary fix...

Comment: Is the comma after `curve->setPen( Qt::blue, 4 ),` a typo? It should be ';' at the end.

Comment: Yep, that was a typo, I already fixed it but didn't change the code in the clipboard...

Comment: Did you try to call `curve->setPen(Qt::blue, 4.0, Qt::SolidLine);`?

Comment: Do you include the right version of `#include <qwt_plot_curve.h>` file? The mentioned API is for Qwt 6.1.1.

Comment: After I only installed qwt-6.1.1, I think this should be the right API (or how can I check if I have more than one version of Qwt installed?)